# Cumulative count of events

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider an active chat room which has less than $N$ messages so far, each with a timestamp.

How can I determine the first day where the expected cumulative message count has a $k$ chance of exceeding $N$?

If I believed that the time between consecutive messages was exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, then I could solve for the Poisson distribution. However I don't know whether that's a valid assumption. Is there a general way of getting an answer from the real data points, or do I have to choose a distribution model based on which assumptions I believe are valid?

Is this an ill-defined problem?

Comment: Your assumption seems reasonable, but may be violated if the events are not independent from one anther.  For example, is the probability of  a chat occurring from person A at time t, independent from another chat occuring at time t-s.  Test the data to see if it conforms to a poisson model. One does not have to separate the world into valid and invalid models.  Models may be approximate and thus be biased.  So if your time constraints are such that searching for the perfect model is impossible, the Poisson may be a good bet.  A